# Resizable one way in grid layout javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with resizable an element in grid layout. When I resize meeting element. It's extend width of it's element both right and left. I only want extend width to the right. I try direction : 'ltr' in css but it's not working. This is my code CSS for resizable width.

```
  ul .chart-li-two-a {
    grid-column: 2/2;
    background-color: #0080ff;
    resize: horizontal;
    direction: "ltr";
  }
```

Here is sandbox code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mountain-kwhx3?file=/index.html&fbclid=IwAR30ftmXwrtvIK4l_1sbOArcAB89x2Za-H9m_wreJtTEOp8Q44dvGyWiVWw)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I have updated code and sandbox code. Please help me if you know any solution.